# Loading data into Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to Insert the string of 1 million size into the Redshift. I tried using different compression method given by Redshift but after some particular length, Redshift also truncate the data. Any suggestion?

Comment: consider adding more information about your question

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no enough information in your question to provide an answer. (In fact, I don't even know what you are asking!) Please edit your question to provide more information. Are you saying that each **row** of data is 1 million characters long? Or one **column** is 1 million characters long? Or are you trying to load 1 million rows? More information please!

Comment: if you explain what you are going to do with it once its there - we can then help

Answer (score 0):

The maximum `VARCHAR` size in Redshift is 65,535 bytes. You'll have to split your string across multiple columns or multiple rows.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html

Comment: Or I believe 4x less than this if you have 4 byte utf chars

Comment: Sure, it's measured in bytes. It would be very unusual to have exclusively 4 byte characters though.